# Missing password parameter in Hive2Server hook

Tags: airflow

Do you have any idea why argument password is missing in the connect module in Hive2Server hook ?

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py

```
from pyhive.hive import connect
        return connect(
            host=db.host,
            port=db.port,
            auth=auth_mechanism,
            kerberos_service_name=kerberos_service_name,
            username=db.login or username,
            database=schema or db.schema or 'default')
```

Basically don't see option to connect with password without changing that code.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like that Airflow hook doesn't support LDAP or CUSTOM, which are the two PyHive auth systems that require a password parameter. Your options are either to change the code or to create another hook that ineherit from the HiveServer2Hook and adds more authentication options.

Comment: Yup I did first. I was just wondering if there is a known reason that Airflow doesnt support it.